# No admin account on Big Sur

Tags: administrator

i updated my mothers macbook air 2014 to Big Sur, I had problems during install and finished the install in safe mode. after restarting i was prompted with her old login screen which accepted her old passsword, this transitioned me to a new second login screen, there i have to login in with a new password. Once logged in i have no admin privileges. i have tried booting into single user mode and do not have permission to mount the drive, i try recovery mode but after entering her apple id i am only prompted to restart and cant access terminal. can anyone point me to another solution, im thinking of downgrading her OS but i cant even back up her documents with out admin access. sorry for grammar i have been working on this all day and im a pc guy.

Comment: I also tried deleting the apple setup up file but did not have permission. I also can’t create a bootable drive because I have no admin account. I’m truly lost, do I have to manually extract all the documents onto a external drive and do a completely fresh install?

Comment: If the existing solutions in the linked question don't solve the issue for you, detail the exact steps you're following with the exact commands you're entering and the exact error messages produced.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/79235) post on Apple's site would help to resolve the issue. You can find a whole procedure with all steps required.

Will put a procedure here for quick reference.

Boot to single user mode with `⌘-S` keystroke.

Remount root with commands:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
/sbin/mount -uw /
```

Delete "setup done" flag:

```
rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

Reboot:

```
reboot
```